Buffer changes pitch of the oscillator
I'm in the process of building my first synthesizer (super simple design as I'm new to all of this.) After the output of the oscillator, I put a buffer (using UA741CP) before going into the RC filter. The pitch of the oscillator changes after the buffer stage. As far as I understand that shouldn't happen so I am not sure what is wrong.
This is the oscillator (I'm using a flipped 2N2222):

This is the circuit so far:

This is my breadboard layout:

Here is the video showing you what is going on. THERE ARE SOME POPS SO BRING YOUR VOLUME DOWN PLEASE.
https://youtu.be/XVErtvKOs1E?si=KQCLmRlCpT3GDnqF

What is the buffer? How is it connected? -- Please show on the schematic for clarity.

Where is the base of the NPN transistor connected to?

Tim - it's a simple 741 voltage follower buffer. I updated the schematic in my main post.

sai - base is not connected to anything.

Does the 741 op-amp even have a power supply? We don't know the breadboard internal wiring, do you?

@sai it's a somewhat-well-known connection, using the three-layer transistor as a snapback diode of sorts; E-B avalanche causes charges to flow into C, and I think something about base region thinning or even punch-through with negative resistance or sudden switching as the outcome. So it acts like a neon tube of old.

You have a crude relaxation oscillator that is very sensitive to load impedance. When you plug the input of your amplifier directly into it, the input resistance of the amplifier reduces the oscillator frequency — probably by forming a voltage divider with the resistors in the oscillator. In fact, you can hear the frequency changing as you plug and unplug it.
However, when you plug the amplifier into the output of your 741 buffer, which has a much higher input impedance, this load is gone, and the oscillator runs at a significantly higher frequency. So the buffer is doing exactly what it is supposed to do — isolate the oscillator from the effects of output loading.
